# Can a Hexblood cast Hex and Disguise Self on the same day?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, racial-traits

There is some disagreement between myself and a friend as to the interpretation of the following feature:

> **Hex Magic.** You can cast the *disguise self* and *hex* spells with this trait. Once you cast either of these spells with this trait, you can't cast that spell with it again until you finish a long rest. (...)

Answer (score 13):

### Yes

You can cast both of those spells, because of the use of the words **either** and **that** in the feature description. The ability to cast them is entirely separate.

Comment: This is correct.  If casting hex precluded casting disguise self, the wording would be "can't use this feature again until you finish a long rest."  To make this answer more complete, you could find an example of class features with that wording and provide it for comparison.